# AS health code problems

Tags: actionscript-3

OK. I'm brand new to AS3 so please be patient with me. My health code is missing something. The health reduces by one, but only when the obstacle is hit the first time. The end result is a score of 19 at the end of the game - even when the obstacle is hit every time. Here is my code. I would greatly appreciate some help here.

```
var hitObstacle:Boolean=false; // keeps track if obstacle is hit
var health=20; 
health_txt.text=health.toString();


stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, jump);
function jump(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
jumpman_mc.play();
}
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameloop);
function gameloop(e:Event):void{
obstacle_mc.x-=20;
if (obstacle_mc.x<-100){
obstacle_mc.x=650;
}
if (jumpman_mc.hitTestObject(obstacle_mc)) {
if (hitObstacle==false){ //only subtract health if hitObstacle is false
health--;
}
hitObstacle=true;
health_txt.text=health.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: This is a Q&A site, not a "fix your code for you" site. Please spend some time on research and study. If you've failed to understand something, ask that precise question here. Don't expect people to do your coding for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't make a comment yet because I don't have enough reputation =/.

But lol, people are so mean over here. "we're not here to fix anything, go away". Don't they remember when they didn't had a clue at all?

Well, the first thing you need to do is to debug your code. You need to check if the code you wrote is actually being called. You can do that by simpling adding a **trace("")** and checking the console when running the app. If you learn to do that you'll be able to catch issues like this in a glimpse.

It looks like the problem is that hitObstacle boolean that you created. You wrote that the health will only be subtracted when hitObstacle is false. Then you set it as true after the first hitTest but you never set it back to false. That will always give you a 20 - 1 health. And anyway, what's that point of that variable? I would remove it altogether.

```
if (jumpman_mc.hitTestObject(obstacle_mc)) {
    health--;
    health_txt.text=health.toString();
}
```

If this doesn't help, then debug your code! =)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not setting the value of "hitObstacle" back to false.

I assume that you're setting "hitObstacle" to true in order to avoid having the health decrement continuously while the objects are touching.

Instead, I'd suggest removing "hitObstacle" and moving the "obstacle_mc" on the stage so that the hitTest evaluates to false after it is hit, e.g.

```
if (jumpman_mc.hitTestObject(obstacle_mc)) {
    health --;
    obstacle_mc.x = 650;
}
```